# What does the 'none' mean in 'mount' command?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

The following command confuse me:

```
# mkdir /dev/mqueue
# mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
```

what does the `none` mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. I'd normally recommend migrating it, but the existing answer already links to an answer on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ that answers it. (I don't think it's possible to close a question as a duplicate of a question on another site -- though I haven't actually tried it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136646/what-is-type-none-for-mount-points-and-why-are-mount-points-of-the-same-type-b

"The none just means that there is no physical disk partition linked to the `mount` point you see when issuing the `mount` command. It is used for virtual filesystems like `shm`, `ramfs`, `proc` and `tmpfs`. The lock, `shm` and user `mount` points in this example are created separately so they can be mounted with different permissions and settings."
 -- captcha